# Where is the Genji Armour?

Tags: crisis-core-final-fantasy-7

I am trying to unlock the Genji Armour in *Crisis Core: Final Fantasy VII*, but I can't seem to find it.

I have looked everywhere in all the missions, but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2):

[According to one article](http://www.mahalo.com/crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-genji-armor/):

> The Genji Armor […] can only be obtained by completing the DMW Gallery. […] Achieve 100% DMW Limit

Related equipment can be acquired to complete the set:

- [Genji Helmet](http://www.mahalo.com/crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-genji-helmet/): Network Shop Shade for 1 million Gil
- [Genji Shield](http://www.mahalo.com/crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-genji-shield/): Mission 7-6-6 in the magic pot
- [Genji Glove](http://www.mahalo.com/crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-genji-glove/): Mission 9-6-4 in a locked treasure chest

Comment: but I heard that you can get more pices from missions

Comment: @samuel If you mean the other pieces of the Genji equipment beyond the Armor, I've added that to the answer, from the same site's information

Comment: I have got all the DMW charecters but not 100 percent limet in every thing, I dont know how to increes it, I have finished the game 6 times